# Walnut Tree Danglies?

Tags: pests, walnut

I have a medium-sized black walnut tree in my yard in north-east Ohio. Recently I noticed these strange things dangling from the bottom of the lower branches. Picture below. Any ideas as to what they might be? I do not believe they are webworms, as I see no worms and they look nothing like webworms I've seen before. There are no obvious insects on the tree.
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Possibly the fruiting part of a fungus that's gotten in where the branch was cut off or broken (old mostly-healed over bit to the left of the danglies.)

Comment: a close up picture or two would help